# What do I miss in this code? it is about String manipulation. I wrote the code, for second case it doesn't work properly. any help appreciated

Tags: string

package day17_StringPractice;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class warmup2 {
/*
2. Ask the user to enter a word. If the first or second or both letter of the word is x,
print the word without x(s). If x is the third letter it should be printed. If the first and second are x, both should be ignored.

```
                Input:
                    xxode

                Output:
                    ode

                Input:
                    oxidex
                Output:
                    oidex
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word: ");
    String word = scan.next();

    boolean firstX =word.charAt(0)=='x';
    boolean secondX = word.charAt(1)=='x';
    if(firstX){
        System.out.println(word.substring(1));
    }else if (firstX && secondX ){
        System.out.println(word.substring(2));
    }else if(secondX){
        System.out.println(word.substring(0,1) + (word.substring(2)));
    }else{
        System.out.println(word);
    }



}
```

}

Comment: My second case doesn't work properly. what should I do? any help is appreciated

Comment: Just fixed it, thank you though